# Problems with releasing an object and closing a spreadsheet?

Tags: c#

I am using EPPlus to open a spreadsheet and then populate it with pictures and information.
When i try to delete a folder containing all the pictures i used to populate my spreadsheet i get the error that this file is in use with another application. What would be the correct way to release the objects used and close the spreadsheet?

```
using (var package = new ExcelPackage(existingFile))
     {
        ExcelWorkbook workBook = package.Workbook;
        if (workBook != null)
        {
          if (workBook.Worksheets.Count > 0)
            {
              int i = 0;
              foreach(ExcelWorksheet worksheet in workBook.Worksheets)
              {
                xlWorkSeet1[i] = worksheet;
                i = i + 1;
              }

            }
        }

           //More code ...

           FileStream aFile = new FileStream(tempFolderPathAlt + saveas + ".xls",    FileMode.Create);
           byte[] byData = package.GetAsByteArray();
           aFile.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
           aFile.Write(byData, 0, byData.Length);
           aFile.Close();

            xlWorkSeet1 = null;
            workBook = null;


      }//End using

     String P = Path.Combine(tempFolderPathAlt, "ExtractedFiles");
     bool directoryExists = Directory.Exists(P);
     if (directoryExists)
     Directory.Delete(P, true); // deletes sub-directories
```

The error i get is when it is trying to delete a photo i added to my spreadsheet.

[image]

Comment: I must admit that i don't understand the code completely, why do you write to a `xls` file when writing to a Epplus `xlsx` file? Maybe the `xls` file still uses the image-file(although you call `aFile.Close()`).

Comment: @TimSchmelter Sorry i did not notice i was saving it as xls when it was xlsx, iv changed that, but it has had no effect on my problem. I think i need to close the package or the WorkBook. I have the package in a using and make the workBook = null but those are not doing the trick.

Comment: Then i don't understand your code at all. Normally you pass the file to the constructor of the `ExcelPackage`. You're passing `existingFile` but you're using a different `FileStream` to write the bytes? I would simply use `package.Save();`.

Comment: I open a spreadsheet template witch is ExistingFile, but i save it as another spreadsheet as to use the template again.

Comment: Then you should wrap two `ExcelPackages` in `ùsing-statements`. One for the template and the other for the new.

Answer (score 0):

Try out following and please let me know whether this helps

```
int writeTimeout = 200;
using (var aFile = new FileStream(tempFolderPathAlt + saveas + ".xls",    FileMode.Create))
{
      aFile.WriteTimeout = writeTimeout;
      byte[] byData = package.GetAsByteArray();            
      aFile.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);            
      aFile.Write(byData, 0, byData.Length);            
      xlWorkSeet1 = null;             
      workBook = null;  
      Thread.Sleep(writeTimeout);
}
```

Comment: I got the following error: Timeouts are not supported on this stream. this appeared at the line of code : aFile.WriteTimeout = writeTimeout;